# how to check modified function formals

Tags: r

In my neverending quest to break things,
consider:

```
gbar<-function(x,y,x,a) x+2*y-4*a
Error: repeated formal argument 'x' on line 1
```

`R` properly checks my defined function for illegal formals.

But if I manually foul things up:

```
 ffoo<-function(x,y,a) x+2*y-4*a
formals(ffoo)<-c(x=7, formals(ffoo))
```

Then I'll only find out under certain circumstances that something is invalid.
`ffoo(3,4,5,6)` will execute properly (although probably not giving me the answer I expected), as will `ffoo(y=3,a=2)`; whereas `ffoo(x=5,y=3,a=2)` will throw an error about ambiguous argument names.

So: is there any `base-R` or advanced utility package with a function to do 'sanity' checking on the `formals` of an existing function?

Comment: I can't find an R function, but you can read the C code at [src/main/gram.y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/cf829c12299b8571cd67e9d8aae88ac31450c73c/src/main/gram.y). Search for the function `CheckFormalArgs()`

Comment: @RichardScriven No, I accepted yr answer.  My final solution was to cross-check the actual names in `formals` and build a `do.call` out of the matches.  I'll post that as an "answer-extension"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you simply want to check for duplicated arguments, you can do this:

```
any(duplicated(names(formals(ffoo))))
# [1] TRUE
```

As Hadley mentions in his second comment below, `dput()` isn't guaranteed to give you a good/complete representation of a function, so there may be functions for which the approach described in my original answer (left in place below) fails.

---

**Original answer:**

As is hinted at in [the C code pointed to by Andrie](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=checkformalargs&type=Code#L165), this is apparently a check that R performs while parsing (not evaluating) a call to `function()`. That's why you were able to circumvent the check with your call to `formals<-`, and it's why the following (for example) also avoids getting checked. In both cases, the function is modified/created without parsing a call to `function()`.

```
eval(call("function", formals(ffoo), body(ffoo)))
# function (x = 7, x, y, a) 
# x + 2 * y - 4 * a
```

R's parsing machinery isn't typically exposed in user-visible R functions, so I'd guess there's no ready-made function R function to perform this check. You could, though, perform the exact same set of checks that R does when you source the expression or enter it at a at a command line by converting the function definition to its character representation and then attempting re-parse it yourself.

Here's the general idea:

```
parse(text = capture.output(dput(ffoo)))
# Error in parse(text = capture.output(dput(ffoo))) : 
#   repeated formal argument 'x' on line 1
```

To wrap the check up as a function do something like this:

```
isParseableFunction <- function(x) {
    tryCatch(is.function(x) & 
             is.expression(parse(text = capture.output(dput(x)))), 
             error = function(e) FALSE)
}

isParseableFunction(data.frame)
# [1] TRUE
isParseableFunction(mean)
# [1] TRUE
isParseableFunction(ffoo)
# [1] FALSE
isParseableFunction(99)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Why not just look at `duplicated(names(formals(ffoo)))`?

Comment: @hadley-- That (or, actually, `any(duplicated(methods::formalArgs("ffoo")))`) was my first thought too, but I decided to give a solution that would implement any other potential unknown-to-me checks that R performs. (That's why my answer mentions performing "the exact same set of checks that R does [...]")

Comment: The problem is that you're trading that against `dput()` giving you a good representation of the function - I've had enough problems in the past, that I don't trust it very much.

Comment: @hadley Can you expand on what the limitations are on `dput(myfunc)` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Here's one example `dput(list(quote(foo)))` (not function related, but shows that `dput()` isn't always high fidelity)